# WCF service in SP2010

Tags: development, web-services, 2007, asp.net

I want to use WCF service in SharePoint 2010 but have problem.

First, in mapped Sp2010 folder(ISAPI) I created newfolder/myfile.svc and in that file I put a reference to my DLL:

```
<%@ServiceHost
    Language="C#" Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    Service="ACIS.WCFService.GraphProccesor, ACIS.WCFService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4ecbdc9be141501"
%>
```

Then, in an additional folder (outside ISAPI) I created WCF service logic (class GraphProccesor, namespace ACIS.WCFService)

I compiled, deployed and everything seems ok. 
in my .dll (c4ecbdc9be141501) - I have namespace and class (same as in above directive), 
in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\ACISWCFService - I have myfile.svc

But when i try to get url of service in IE i got:

> The type 'ACIS.WCFService.GraphProccesor, ACIS.WCFService,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4ecbdc9be141501',
>   provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive
>   could not be found.

Please, any suggestions? Did I forget something additional?

---

**Edit #1:**
Ok, thank you for suggestion but that didn't help. What partially helped is that I added web.config (in first place i forgot that) in _vti_bin/myfolder. Now I getting error message: "Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7)"

When I try to get my svc file with "svcutil.exe" in the way 
"http://dt-slavenl/sites/acis/_vti_bin/ACISWCFService/service.svc"
i got message:

> WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>       URI: http://dt-slavenl/sites/acis/a1/_vti_bin/ACISWCFService/service.svc
>       Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://dt-slavenl/si
>   tes/acis/a1/_vti_bin/ACISWCFService/service.svc'.
>       The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'NTLM'.
>       The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. HTTP GET Error
>       URI: http://dt-slavenl/sites/acis/a1/_vti_bin/ACISWCFService/service.svc
>       The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

---

**Edit #2:** I manage to come "near" my webservice thanks to Marek link. New problem is that when I want to access to web service from IE i got:

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication
>   but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

If somebody know how to configure SP app pool or web.config so that I can access from IE, that would be awesome! If not, my new strategy is to create web part (full trust) with image control which has property "imageurl" set to http handler (.ashx) WHICH then will communicate with my wcf service and give response (image) to image.imageurl. If somebody see some potential problems please let me know. Also any suggestion for best way how to implement proxy or client access (from .ashx) will be appreciated!

Comment: When I enter web service URL in IE I got white screen and not any information about status of my request or possible errors. Same thing is with or without "/mex". Now I'm gonna study your links.

Comment: Did you apply the `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements` and `BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint` attributes to your class? http://answers.oreilly.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=904 The documentation on this is rather poor, but I think that without the 2nd one the `/mex` address will not work.

Comment: I did everything ok(as in links 1,2,3), but the problem was partially described in 4 link. I learned that my web.config in my _vt_bin file is redundant and that my service/binding/behaviours specs of mywebservice must be defined in sharepoint web.config. And for now, Marek I deeply thank you!! New info follows...

Comment: Did you configure your service to use `Anonymous` authentication? Why not `Ntlm`? You log in to SharePoint (using integrated authentication, I suppose) and then the same credentials will be automatically passed to the service. *BTW, you question is getting too big - consider posting other problems as new questions.*

Comment: I got this error Error File Not Found. Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation ID: 1939e647-a05b-491b-be28-0584b26f1070 Error The service '/_vti_bin/WCFSPF/wcfspf.svc' does not exist. Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation ID: 12eb7fca-4a29-4c7b-9c37-86fd0cff2856 Date and Time: 10/10/2011 4:06:39 AM

Comment: Maybe you didn't deployed your dlls (with wcf logic) to GAC. Also, be aware that you put good reference (namespaces and classes name) in .wcfspf file. And as I said while answering to Marek, you MUST have configured correct wcf configuration settings in your web application (web.config) file. All that must be done if you want that your sharepoint instance host wcf service. But my experience shows me that is a better approach to use independent wcf service which you call from sharepoint and/or which give some response to sharepoint client which you can integrate to some web part, custom page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some useful links:

- [How to Customize WCF Services in SharePoint 2010](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1404-how-to-customize-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010/)

  - This is a step-by-step description of how to create and deploy a custom SharePoint WCF service for the first time. There is only caveat - the replaceable parameter `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` (used in [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=905)) is not automatically replaced in the `.svc` files.
- [How Deploy a WCF Service To SharePoint 2010](http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/03/10/how-deploy-a-wcf-service-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

  - Section *Token Replacement in Visual Studio* of this article explains how to solve the problem I mentioned above.
- [WCF Services in SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521586.aspx)
- [Creating a Custom WCF Service in SharePoint Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx)

Comment: Answer to my problem lied at link 4. I didn't put my wcf configuration on right place (in sp web.config). Thanks to Marek that problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. When you create the WCF service project in Visual Studio, the strong name in the key.snk file is tied to the namespace of your project. If you change the namespace after you create the project, it breaks the link to the strong name, and that error results. You need to think about how you want your namespace, and name the project with that namespace when you create the project in Visual Studio. In your case, you would name the project "ACIS.WCFService." If you named the project something else, "Fred" for example, the default namespace declaration would be "Namespace Fred."

Answer (score 0):

Same issue though I opted to use the Community Kit for SharePoint: Development Tools Edition (cksdev.codeplex.com) and it took care of setting up the service correctly.  The only odd issue is that to be able to see/use the Item Template for the WCF Service (CKSDEV), the WCF Service has to be added at the Project level (not at a folder level, which is the recommended approach for adding files in the hive).  Still, I just had to set the Deployment Location's Path property of the .svc file.  I could then call the MEX endpoint and see the configuration.  Tested with the WCF Test Client and it works.